# Would it be possible to shorten or rewrite a code like this in SCSS?

Tags: css, sass

I know this may sound silly but it would be possible to shorten or rewrite a code like this in SCSS or should I just leave it as is?

```
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  letter-spacing: .02em;
  color: $heading-color;
}

h1 {
  margin: .5em 0;
  font-size: 2.6rem;
}

h2 {
  margin: 1em 0;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}

h3 {
  margin: 1.2em 0;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

h4 {
  margin: 1.6em 0;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

Comment: You can use a mixin to store the margin and font-size properties but that won't shorten your code very much.

Comment: Leave it as it is. Does not makes much sense to shorten something here.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you, if you want to shorten your scss code, use loops for "h" tags for setting the margin and font-size.
here is the example how I use it to calculate font-sizes:

```
@for $h from 1 through 6 {
    h#{$h} {
        font-size: $base-font-size + $heading-scale * (6 - $h);

      }
  }
```

Where:

```
$h: 1;
$base-font-size: 1rem;
$heading-scale: 0.2;
written in variables.
```

So you can take whatever base size you want and use the scale to increase the size dynamically.

In my example it would be in the output css file:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 2rem; }

h2 {
  font-size: 1.8rem; }

h3 {
  font-size: 1.6rem; }

h4 {
  font-size: 1.4rem; }

h5 {
  font-size: 1.2rem; }

h6 {
  font-size: 1rem; }
```

In the same manner you can set margins.